# Macro to call datasets and concatenate it

Tags: macros, sas, concatenation

I know to how to call different tables from my folder. This is done with the `function : %let x1 = libname.foldername`. My problem is how to do it on 1000 tables with a simple macro

SAS

```
%Let Table1=project.table_201710; 
%Let Table2=project.table_201711;
%Let Table3=project.table_201712;
%Let Table4=project.table_201801;
%Let Table5=project.table_201802; 
%Let Table6=project.table_201803;
%Let Table7=project.table_201804;
%Let Table8=project.table_201805;
%Let Table9=project.table_201806;
%Let Table10=project.table_201807;
%Let Table11=project.table_201808;
%Let Table12=project.table_201809;

%Macro ConcatTable;
Data project.TABLE_FINALE; 
Set
%Do i=1 %To 12;
&&Table&i. 
%End;
;
Run;
%Mend ConcatTable;
%ConcatTable
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would avoid moving data from datasets into macro variables.

The first thing to try is to not use macro coding at all. Try just using dataset lists.  If you can find one or more common prefixes for the datasets you want.

```
data project.TABLE_FINALE; 
  set project.TABLE_20: ;
run;
```

If you did want to put the list into macro variables then it is conceptually clearer and the coding is easier if you just put the list into a single macro variable.

```
proc sql noprint;
  select dsname into :dslist separated by ' '
  from mylist;
quit;

data project.TABLE_FINALE; 
  set &dslist;
run;
```

But if you really have a 1,000 datasets then that might be too many to put into a single macro variable (limit 65K characters).

You can also just generate the code from the data instead of using a macro to generate the code.  Then there is no need to move any of the data into macro variables. For example you could use `CALL EXECUTE()` .

```
data _null_;
  set mylist end=eof;
  if _n_=1 then call execute('data project.TABLE_FINALE; set');
  call execute(' '||trim(dsname));
  if eof then call execute(';run;');
run;
```